# jquery animate() function is not triggering on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a form with multiple child elements like below. In my CSS I initialized this form to be completely transparent and with jQuery `.animate()` I would like it to move upwards and become opaque when I click a button.

In jQuery, I am first loading the parent element from a separate PHP file and making the parent element visible in CSS. Then I am calling animate on `modal-content` which is not working.

```js
$(".purchase").on("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked");

  $(".modal").load("login_signup_popup.php");
  $(".modal").css("display", "block");

  $(".modal-content").animate({
    opacity: 1,
    top: "100px"
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.modal-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 500px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 80%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", serif;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="purchase">Purchase</a>
<form class="modal-content" action="/SignUp.php">
  <input type="text" id="foo" name="foo" />
</form>
```

Comment: I placed the code in an executable snippet in the question where it appears to work absolutely fine. Please check your local version for errors in the console.

Comment: There are absolutely no errors. so there must be some CSS interference from something else right?  modal (The parent) is invisible at first and just before the animation its displayed. This is not shown in the above snippet could this be the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's possible too.

Answer (score 1):

Your `load()` method is asynchronous. Meaning, it doesn't necessarily complete before the code following it. So, attach any code you want executed after the `load()` in a callback attached as the second parameter argument.

```js
$(".purchase").on("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked");

  $(".modal").load("login_signup_popup.php",
function() {
         $(".modal").css("display", "block");

         $(".modal-content").animate({
             opacity: 1,
             top: "100px"
         }, 2000);
    });
 
});
```

```css
.modal-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 500px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 80%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", serif;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="purchase">Purchase</a>
<form class="modal-content" action="/SignUp.php">
  <input type="text" id="foo" name="foo" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. The problem was that I wrote the PHP in another file and was loading that PHP file on click. when I placed  `$(".modal").load("login_signup_popup.php");`  in the beginning of the jquery document, the animation worked. Could someone give a reason why this happens? why does the loading of the PHP snippet has to be done much earlier?